# My code says that the role is not found when using reaction roles command

Tags: python, discord.py

So, everything is basically said in the title. I have this code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    channel = await self.bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    user = message.guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji
    if message.id == 849352038801211403:
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "[Role]")
        if emoji.id == 849345681277452328: await user.add_roles(user, Apex)
        else:
            await channel.send("Incorrect emoji")
            await message.remove_reaction(emoji, user)
```

And it is saying this error:

```
    Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mbuxiq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\mbuxiq\Desktop\Code\Bot\Cogs\serverRelated.py", line 66, in on_raw_reaction_add
    if emoji.id == 849345681277452328: await user.add_roles(user, Apex)
  File "C:\Users\mbuxiq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 676, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\mbuxiq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 243, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
```

I am clueless on what should I do. Please, help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message states `Unknown Role` @ `await user.add_roles(user, Apex)`!

First of all, `Apex` isn't declared in the code you provided. Make sure it is when you call it. But since it didn't throw a `NameError` I guess it is.

Second of all, `user` is of type `discord.Member` since you declare it as

```
user = message.guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
```

But [`await discord.Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) only takes `discord.Role` as arguments **not members!** This is where your error comes from. You're trying to assign a member as a role, which doesn't make sense at all. Simply removing `user` from your `add_roles` function call should fix your isse

---

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    channel = await self.bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    user = message.guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji
    if message.id == 849352038801211403:
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "[Role]")
        if emoji.id == 849345681277452328: 
            await user.add_roles(Apex)
        else:
            await channel.send("Incorrect emoji")
            await message.remove_reaction(emoji, user)
```

Comment: Weird. It worked on the first time, but now it's returning an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'. The error is showing in the 10th line of code: if emoji.id == 849345681277452328:

Comment: Nevermind. I reinstalled python and it works consistently.